# eclipse-integration-gradle plugin requires sample project download -- override?

Tags: spring, eclipse-plugin, gradle, spring-tool-suite

**Description**: I'm attempting to use the [eclipse-integration-gradle plugin new project wizard](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/wiki/New-gradle-project-wizard) but when selecting one of the required "Sample projects" I receive an error when the tool attempts to download the samples (proxy error). Resolving the proxy error (via auth and allowing the download) is not an acceptable option for me in this situtation.

**Question**: Is there a way to override this behavior to point to a location on the file system (or my own remote location) for these example projects instead? I've toyed around with the settings in Window > Preferences > Gradle (namely the Gradle Dist. setting) but no avail. I haven't found too many resources online, the official documentation is linked above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way at the moment to override the location where samples are downloaded from. (Unless you clone the source code, modify it and build your own version).

However there is one sample, the 'flat java multiproject' one, which is not dowloaded remotely but included in the Gradle STS plugin itself. So that sample should work without downloading anything.

If you do need the simpler single-project 'quickstart' sample then you can unfortunately not get it via the new project wizard. You will need to manually unzip it and import it into your workspace. Importing the contents of a copy of the sample from the official distribution, using Gradle Import Wizard will produce a project just like the one that the New Project wizard would produce.